# How to get different javascript keycodes for [ and { and ' and "

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello everyone I am making a text editor which auto completes brackets and quotes using jQuery. To do this I am using key codes, however it appears that [ and { share a keycode (same as " and '). How can I differentiate between these in the below function:

```
$("#input").on("keyup", function(e) {
   if (e.which == 219) {}
});
```

Comment: `which` is deprecated, and never have been reliable when checking special characters. Take a look at [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).

Comment: @Teemu I can not find where this answers my question

Comment: Please read the article ...

Comment: check for the shift key if it's pressed

Comment: @AlexHawking Teemus comment very specifically addresses the issue; go with the `key` property of `KeyboardEvent` instead of the deprecated `which`.

Comment: There is a difference between "which key was pressed" and "what character did the key press generate". In most cases, you want to know the second, which is where [*KeyboardEvent.key*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) is useful. It also takes into consideration any modifier keys that were also pressed. If only the method had been named *getCharacter* or similar instead…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[KeyboardEvent#which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) is deprecated.

Use [KeyboardEvent#key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

I.E. `e.key === '['` or `e.key === '{'`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for to get a different key code for `{` and `[` or `'` and `"`. But if you want to check if the key is `{` of `[` you can use the following logic:

```js
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
   if (e.which == 219 && e.shiftKey) {
     console.log('{ was pressed');
    }
   if (e.which == 219 && !e.shiftKey) {
     console.log('[ was pressed');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can directly check by using `e.key === '{'` and `e.key ==='['`

Hope it helps.

Comment: You need to check for more than just *shiftKey*. Pressing [ + shift + option gives double quote ("), the above code will return {.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```js
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.which == 219 && e.shiftKey) {
    console.log('perssed:{');
  } else if (e.which == 219 && (!e.shiftKey)) {
    console.log('perssed:[');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to check for more than just *shiftKey*. Pressing [ + shift + option gives double quote ("), the above code will return {.

Comment: i didn't use Mac So sorry